# Set ValidationFlags when using the Validate() extension method

Tags: c#, xml, validation, schema, linq-to-xml

I want to validate an XML against a schema and set certain validation flags. I know that I can set ValidationFlags when validating an XML stream like so:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { 
  Schemas = schemas;
  ValidationFlags = ...; // HERE
};
settings.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationErrorHandler;

using(var stream = ...)
{
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
    XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

However, if I already have an existing XDocument, the MSDN says I should validate like so:

```
myDoc.Validate(schemas, MyValidationErrorHandler);
```

But how to set the ValidationFlags in this scenario?

Comment: Does this help at all?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232575/xdocument-validate-is-always-successful

Comment: I guess you have to call `myDoc.CreateReader()`, then modify settings of that reader and validate using it

Comment: I agree with @Evk, the suggested way of using flags for validation appears to be a Reader.